# Dropdown item text in AngularJS, bootstrap gets chopped from bottom

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

My dropdown has several values, when clicks on dropdown to see the list, grey has full 'y'. Upon selection, bottom portion of Grey gets chopped. This is happening with all similar characters.

[image]

Edit:

```
<div class="col-lg-6"><div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attrib in col1Attribs">
    <div ng-class="invalidCodeClass">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtCode">{{attrib.displayText}}</label>
        <select id="ddl{{attrib.configType}}" class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="c in configOptions(attrib.configType)" value="{{c.configId}}">{{c.configValue}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your current code for the dropdown? CSS specifically.

Comment: It's hard to check the problem unless you create a live version of it.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a fixed height on that select node

Comment: I am using bootstrap. We didn't customize anything. Is it a bug with bootstrap itself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in your `html` or `js` code but rather with the `css` applied by the particular browser with which you are viewing the page.

Try changing the (font) styling on the select list; some suggestions:

**1.** reducing font size

**2.** increase line-height on select

**3.** removing styling options on select as @yuujin has suggested.

Probably with one of those changes you will be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am looking for bootstrap based solution as this issue is same across my site.